# What is it about this Javascript code that causes it to correctly generate a table in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-table

What is it about this source code that causes it to actually generate a table in IE instead of just doing nothing.

```
        function generateATable()
        {
            tableContainer = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
            var tableElement = document.createElement("table");

            // Append the Table Element to the table 
            // container.
            tableContainer.appendChild(tableElement);

            // IE Requires a TBODY when dynamically generating 
            // tables.  (I thought this was it but apparently it isn't)
            var tbodyElement = document.createElement("tbody");

            // First we'll append the tbody.
            tableElement.appendChild(tbodyElement);

            var trElement1 = document.createElement("tr");

            // Next we'll append the first trElement to the 
            // tbody.
            tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement1);

            var aaCell = trElement1.insertCell(-1);
            var abCell = trElement1.insertCell(0);

            var textNodeAA = document.createTextNode("AA");
            var textNodeAB = document.createTextNode("AB");

            aaCell.appendChild(textNodeAA);
            abCell.appendChild(textNodeAB);

            tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement1);

            var baCell = trElement1.cells[0].cloneNode(false);
            var bbCell = trElement1.cells[1].cloneNode(false);

            var textNodeBA = document.createTextNode("BA");
            var textNodeBB = document.createTextNode("BB");

            trElement2 = trElement1.cloneNode(false);

            tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement2);

            baCell.appendChild(textNodeBA);
            bbCell.appendChild(textNodeBB);

            trElement2.appendChild(baCell);
            trElement2.appendChild(bbCell);

            tableElement.style.border="4px solid black";

        }
```

---

My apologies...it's a problem with something else...the data that was creating the table wasn't filling in, votes back up for everyone...sorry!...

Answer (score 7):

```
                    tableContainer = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
                    var tableElement = document.createElement("table");

                    // Append the Table Element to the table 
                    // container.
                    tableContainer.appendChild(tableElement);
```

That's about it. The rest is actually populating the table.

We find a div in the existing HTML document called "tableDiv", and then we create a <table> element, and add it to tableDiv.

Comment: I'm pretty certain there's more to it than that...because you can't just append children directly to a <TR>, you have to call insertCell to create a "<TD>" element.  

Also it seems to me that it's a requirement to have the tbody appended to the table first...but there has to be more to it than that

Comment: But, the OP is doing all of that stuff.

Comment: leeand00: The code is doing all the things you say, it is appending a tbody to the table, a tr to the tbody, inserting cells, appending text to those cells and appending those cells to the tr. That is what Yuliy means when he says: 'That's about it. The rest is actually populating the table'.

Comment: well I'm glad I didn't respond to this Q if the OP is just downvoting every response he mystically doesn't feel to be correct...

Answer (score 4):

Creating a table which can be seen on the page consists of two steps — creating the table node:

```
var tableElement = document.createElement("table");
```

…and adding it as the child of a node which is in the document:

```
tableContainer = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
tableContainer.appendChild(tableElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.createElement("table")
  ...
tableContainer.appendChild(tableElement);
```

That adds a  element to the DOM.

Comment: Nope, Just creates an element in memory.  To put it on the page you'd have to append it to another element already on the page, or do a document.write.

Comment: quibbling - he's pointing out what createElement and appendChild which is what matters

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're downvoting everyone who has answered correctly. Do you want a line-by-line description of what the code is doing?

```
function generateATable() {
    /* obtain a reference to a div */
    tableContainer = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
    /* create a table element */
    var tableElement = document.createElement("table");

    // Append the Table Element to the table 
    // container.
    /* append the table element to the div */
    tableContainer.appendChild(tableElement);

    // IE Requires a TBODY when dynamically generating 
    // tables.  (I thought this was it but apparently it isn't)
    /* create a tbody element */
    var tbodyElement = document.createElement("tbody");

    // First we'll append the tbody.
    /* append the tbody element to the table element */
    tableElement.appendChild(tbodyElement);

    /* create a row element */
    var trElement1 = document.createElement("tr");

    // Next we'll append the first trElement to the 
    // tbody.
    /* append the row element to the tbody element */
    tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement1);

    /* insert two cells */
    var aaCell = trElement1.insertCell(-1);
    var abCell = trElement1.insertCell(0);

    /* create two text nodes */
    var textNodeAA = document.createTextNode("AA");
    var textNodeAB = document.createTextNode("AB");

    /* append the text nodes to the cells */
    aaCell.appendChild(textNodeAA);
    abCell.appendChild(textNodeAB);

    /* append the row element to the tbody element ... again */
    tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement1);

    /* create two new cells that are shallow copies of the two cells above */
    var baCell = trElement1.cells[0].cloneNode(false);
    var bbCell = trElement1.cells[1].cloneNode(false);

    /* create two more text nodes */
    var textNodeBA = document.createTextNode("BA");
    var textNodeBB = document.createTextNode("BB");

    /* create a row element that is a shallow copy of the first row */
    trElement2 = trElement1.cloneNode(false);

    /* append the 2nd row element to the tbody element */
    tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement2);

    /* append the text nodes to the cells */
    baCell.appendChild(textNodeBA);
    bbCell.appendChild(textNodeBB);

    /* append the cells to the 2nd row element */
    trElement2.appendChild(baCell);
    trElement2.appendChild(bbCell);

    /* set the border style of the table element */
    tableElement.style.border="4px solid black";
}
```

Comment: how do you combat this behaviour? the question itself doesn't deserve a downvote, nor is it offensive...